# Как можно сделать края у дива как на фото которое я прикрепил?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Изображение чека который я хочу сверстать

Comment: Можно с помощью svg или css gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS3 со своими градиентами творят чудеса! По-моему, похоже получилось:

```css
body{margin:0;height:100vh;background-color:#e5e5e5;background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png);background-position:0% 0%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto;display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;align-items:center}

.ticket {
  height: 90%; width: 90%;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 1px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(to right, #000 8px, transparent 8px, transparent 30px), linear-gradient(to right, #000 8px, transparent 8px, transparent 30px), linear-gradient(to bottom, #dff1f6, #f9fcfd), radial-gradient( circle closest-side, transparent 9px, #000 10px, #dff1f6 11px), radial-gradient( circle closest-side, transparent 9px, #000 10px, #f9fcfd 11px);
  background-size: 1px 100%, 30px 1px, 30px 1px, 100% calc(100% - 24px), 30px 22px, 30px 22px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 12px, 4px -10px, 4px calc(100% - -10px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-x, no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-x;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 3px #000a);
}
```

```html
<div class="ticket"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

примерно так:

```css
body,
header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*height of wave = h = 50px*/
header {
  background: darkblue;

  width:  400px;
  height: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 50px; /*h*/

position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header:before,
header:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 25px; /*h/2*/
  height: 50px; /*h*/
  background: radial-gradient(closest-side, #fff, #fff 50%, transparent 50%);
  /*or farthest-side*/
  background-size: 50px 50px; /*h h*/
  background-position: 0 25px; /*0 h/2*/
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

header:after {
  background: radial-gradient(
    closest-side,
    transparent,
    transparent 50%,
    #fff 50%
  );
  /*or farthest-side*/
  background-size: 50px 50px; /*h h*/
  background-position: 25px -25px; /*h/2 -h/2*/
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  bottom: -25px;
}
```

```html
<header class="wave">
</header>
```